# Variable declaration without an 'As' clause; type of Object assumed

Tags: vb.net, form-control

I have this **`form`**

[image]

And I have this **`code`**

```
'For Tab Schedule
Dim Schedule_Tab = frmSettings.Tab_Schedule.Controls 'the tab page for schedule
Dim Panel_Set_Num As String
Dim Set_Num As String = "00"

Public Function Schedule_Get() As String
    For Each Ctrl_Panel_Set As Control In Schedule_Tab
        If TypeOf Ctrl_Panel_Set Is Panel And Ctrl_Panel_Set.Name.StartsWith("Panel_Set_") Then
            For Each Ctrl_Lbl_Temp In Ctrl_Panel_Set.Controls
                If TypeOf Ctrl_Lbl_Temp Is Label Then
                    If Ctrl_Lbl_Temp.Name.StartsWith("Lbl_Temp_") Then
                        If Ctrl_Lbl_Temp.Text = "0" Then
                            Panel_Set_Num = CType(Ctrl_Panel_Set, Panel).Name
                            Set_Num = "CSR" & Panel_Set_Num.Substring(Panel_Set_Num.Length - 2) & "^"
                            Return Set_Num
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next Ctrl_Panel_Set
    Return "Done"
End Function
```

And I have this **`error`**

> **1.** Variable declaration without an 'As' clause; type of Object assumed.
>   
>   
>   **2.** Warning treated as error : Variable declaration without an 'As' clause; type of Object assumed.

The **`emphasize`** of the error is in this line of code.

```
Dim Schedule_Tab = frmSettings.Tab_Schedule.Controls 'the tab page for schedule
```

I tried to follow what the error says so I **`changed`** `Dim Schedule_Tab` to `Dim Schedule_Tab As Form.ControlCollection` but it result in this kind of error **`An unhandled exception of type System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in xxxxxxxxx.exe`**.

**`Questions:`**

1. What should I do in that situation?
2. How should I declare **`Schedule_Tab`**?

Comment: Why do you need a duplicate reference to a Controls collection?  It will always be there as a member of the Tab control.

Comment: Try using `new` keyword `Dim Schedule_Tab As new Form.ControlCollection`(assuming this is the correct type, i'm not sure what frmSettings is)

Answer (score 1):

It should be declared like this:

```
Dim Schedule_Tab As Control.ControlCollection = frmSettings.Tab_Schedule.Controls
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Dim Schedule_Tab as New frmSettings.Tab_Schedule.Controls
```